# How do I fix this on Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Whenever I try and draw in Adobe Illustrator the lines always do this weird thing where they sort of fill in a bit... 
How do I stop this?
As it is really annoying while trying to draw...
Thank you
[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solving this problem requires access to a specific setup, or interaction with you or your machine. There are a lot of possible reasons why this could be happening.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

### Simplify the vector points

After drawing go to menu **Object** > **Path** > **Simplify**

Reducing the number of vector points to 90% fix the problem and the drawing remains almost unchanged:

[image]

### Draw bigger

[image]