# Strange random corners with brush

Tags: adobe-illustrator, brush

[image: corner]

How to get rid or manage these artificial "corner fill"?

Comment: In addition to the duplicates above - this question doesn't have a selected answer, but it may be helpful: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/117718/how-do-i-fix-this-on-adobe-illustrator

Comment: Essentially teh issue is anchor points which are too close together for the brush to effectively draw a brush stroke. Work larger or simplify the anchor points.